# Merging beams using critical angles

Tags: optics, visible-light

If I were to send two beams into an optically dense object such that they are both incident at the critical angle as they try to leave, will both the beams merge at the end of the material? Below is a drawing of what I mean:
[image: Beam merging using critical angles]

Comment: Please is it possible to know what is the material?

Comment: I was just thinking about it in general. An example would be some sort of glass as the block whilst the surrounding area is just air.

Comment: Note that if your drawing (v1) is of a single rectangular block of high-index material in a low-index environment (e.g. glass brick in air), and the geometry at the upper surface is at the boundary between critical-angle transmission and total internal reflection, your ray geometry at the lower surface doesn't obey Snell's Law.  For a practical device you would need to consider the angular divergence of each beam, and you would be very sensitive to the condition of the upper surface.

Answer (score 0):

While this may work initially i.e the beams will be superposed on one another along the interface, it would scatter once it reaches the edge, much like [knife edge diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife-edge_effect).